# Use API Gateway with authentication from Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-cloud-sql, gateway

I have micro services running on Cloud Run, and I want to leverage API Gateway.

Is it possible to use API Gateway to authenticate my users with a Cloud Function or a container in Cloud Run that consults the user's data from a database in Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: you can't.

With API gateway, you have a limited number of [built-in authentication method](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method). In short, you have API Key (not really recommended because it's a long lived token) and OAuth2 (JWT token with FirebaseAuth/Cloud Identity Platform, Okta, Auth0, or a custom IdP).

In your case, if you want to use your own database for you own users, you need to plug, in front of your Cloud SQL database, a OAuth Identity Provider and implement the business logic that you want. And then, use API Gateway with a custom IDP.

But, the easiest is to use Firebase or [Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform) (which is the implementation of FirebaseAuth in GCP). The users aren't in your database, but you can imagine synchronization (API Calls).